# Calculating volume using double integral when domain is in two quarters

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

In my exam there was a problem saying:

> Show that $\iint\limits_s f(x,y)\,dxdy = ln2\int_1^2f(u)\,du$ where $s$ is in the first quarter and between $y=4x$, $y=x$, $xy=2$ and $xy=1$.

I used these variable changes:

- $u=xy$
- v = $\dfrac{y}{x}$

And I could succesfully prove the equation. But my question is, if the sentence "is in the first quarter" was omitted from the problem, would it be diferrent? When we calculate $\iint\limits_s f(x,y)\,dxdy$, we are actually calculating on domain $s$ and it means one in first queter and one in third quarter? Or no, it calculates only on one of them?

[image]